# Position of an adverb in this sentence

Tags: adverb-position

I hope you can help me. I have recently found this sentence
*"improving safety should not be considered merely a law obligation, but also a concrete economic opportunity"*.
I was wondering if the position of *merely* is correct.
Thank you.

Comment: Where do you believe it belongs?

Answer (score 0):

I'd write this as:

> improving safety should not be considered merely **as** a **legal** obligation, but also a concrete economic opportunity

(*law obligation* is not grammatical).

*merely* could also come after *as*:

> improving safety should not be considered **as** merely a **legal** obligation, but also a concrete economic opportunity

If there is any difference in meaning between the two, it's not apparent to me as a native speaker of UK English.

Comment: Thank you, Alfred. Your help was precious. There was something strange in that sentence but I was not able to figure it out. I thought it was the word _merely_ but it was something worse. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

> Improving safety should not be considered merely a law obligation, but
>   also a concrete economic opportunity"

I would make the following suggestion:

> Improving safety should not be considered merely a **legal** obligation, but
>   also a **real** economic opportunity."

Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The position of the 'merely' with respect to the indefinite article makes a difference.

In "**merely a** legal obligation", the 'merely' refers to the entire noun phrase following it, so would expect a contrast with something other than an obligation.

In your example, that's an "opportunity".

In "**a merely** legal obligation" the 'merely' refers to the adjective "legal", so would expect a contrast with another kind of obligation, for example:

"It is not a merely legal obligation, but also a moral one"